# Filtering dataframe based on other dataframe column on Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames. One contains multiple columns with sample name and rows containing  values. The second DataFrame contains one column called "Sample Name" which contains a list of the names of samples that pass a quality control.
df1

```
| mz   | Sample 001| Sample 002...
|:---- |:---------:| ---------:|
| 234  | 3434      | 34545     |
|:---- |:---------:| ---------:|
| 4542 | 5656563   | 4545      |
```

df2

```
| Sample Name | RT |
| ----------- | ---|
| Sample001   | 8  |
| Sample002   | 8  |...
```

df1 contains more than 2000 rows and 200 columns, df2 contains 180 columns. I want to filter df1 to remove the columns that are NOT present on the df2 column "Sample Name"
The resulting DataFrame should be a version of df1 filtered with 180 columns present on the df2 list.

Answer (score 0):

Se if this works:

```
for col in df1.columns:
    if col not in df2['Sample Name'].unique():
        df1.drop(columns=[col], inplace=True)
```